# Not all prometheus metrics are showing in google Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am exporting prometheus metrics to google stackdriver by following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/prometheus.

When I query into the prometheus, I find all the metrics. But in the stackdriver metrics explorer, I can't find all the metrics( some of the metrics are there).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are aware that metrics imported from Prometheus are [external metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_other#externalgoogleapiscom) for Stackdriver.

As it is stated into the documentation:

> For external metrics, a resource_type of global is invalid and results
>   in the metric data being discarded.

Prometheus exported metrics are those whose name begin with:

> external.googleapis.com/prometheus/

A possible reason for your issue is that you have a limit of metric descriptors that you can export per project. The limit is  10,000 Prometheus-exported metric / project. In case you have more, it is a normal thing for some of the metrics not to be there.

If this is not the problem it should normally be only a configuration issue, as your export actually works. Somehow, some of the metrics are filtered by the collector. Just re-check the way you have managed your configuration parameters ( filters,file etc..). You can check this [documentation](https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar/blob/master/README.md) for more information.

Comment: i found out the quota, but i am sending <1000 metrics.

Comment: I edited my answer adding some additional info that can be reliable to you